# Assigning a variable using readline function in R?

Tags: r, function, readline

Although this should be very simple, I am having an issue with readline function to assign variables.

```
fun <- function(x){
x <- readline(prompt="Please choose your color 'red, blue, yellow' ")
 if (x=="red") {
   x<-1}
 else if (x=="blue") {
   x<-2}
 else if (x=="yellow") {
   x<-3}
 else {print("Please choose the color provided above")}
return(x)
}
```

To me, this simple code should definitely work. Although it seems like working properly, the code is not assigning the new variable (1, 2, or 3) into x. When I run the code, it does return the new value of x, but the new x value is not stored. Could you help me if there is any error in my code? Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t shown how you’re using the function but I’m guessing that you’re trying to call it something like this:

```
foo(x)
```

But what you *should* be doing is call it like this:

```
x = foo()
```

(And `x` doesn’t need to exist beforehand: you’re not overwriting an existing variable, you’re creating a new one.)

In fact, the *argument* `x` to the function is unnecessary (you’re not using it). Furthermore, your function can be simplified quite substantially:

```
fun = function() {
    x = readline(prompt="Please choose your color 'red, blue, yellow' ")
    switch(x, red = 1, blue = 2, yellow = 3,
           stop('Please choose a color provided above'))
}
```

Comment: Ahhh Thanks! I'm new to R and this kind of small issues always bug me. Thanks for the compact (and better) code too.